# functional component is not re-rendering after state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a functional component that retrieves data from an http request on page load and updates the state to store that data using useState. I then try to map out a nested array (polls.pollOptions) from the data, I get an error: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**". If i remove the map function and check the React component extension, I can see that the state was updated and it has the correct data. So why doesn't this render to the screen & why receive an error when the data is there to map through? Heres my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router";

export const EditPolls2 = () => {
  const { _id } = useParams();
  const [polls, setPolls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/polls/${_id}`).then((p) => {
      setPolls(p.data);
    });
  }, [_id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>edit polls 2</p>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {polls.pollOptions.map((p) => (
            <li key={p.pollId}>{p.option}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current initial state is an empty array, and you are trying to access `pollOptions`, which is a property that doesn't exist on an empty array.

If you don't need anything, but `pollOptions`, leave the initial state as an empty array, use `polls` and not `polls.pollOptions` when mapping the data, and make sure to set `pollOptions` as the state:

```
export const EditPolls2 = () => {
  const { _id } = useParams();
  const [polls, setPolls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/polls/${_id}`).then((p) => {
      setPolls(p.data.pollOptions); // set the pollOptions array as the state
    });
  }, [_id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>edit polls 2</p>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {polls.map((p) => ( // use polls and not pollOptions
            <li key={p.pollId}>{p.option}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you do need the entire object (`data`) in the state, don't use initial state, and use [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when mapping the array. If the state is `undefined`, the mapping would be skipped:

```
export const EditPolls2 = () => {
  const { _id } = useParams();
  const [polls, setPolls] = useState(); // no initial state

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/polls/${_id}`).then((p) => {
      setPolls(p.data);
    });
  }, [_id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>edit polls 2</p>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {polls.pollOptions?.map((p) => ( // optional chaining
            <li key={p.pollId}>{p.option}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I do need to retrieve the entire object, in order to get other fields like title, date, etc., but its pollOptions that i was getting an error. Optional chaining was what i needed.